# how to get the values that fullfil the statement in my count?

Tags: mysql

I try to display each pair of actors, the two actors have not played on anyone
common movie genre while at the same time the genre that one has played together with the genre which has been played by the other being at least 7

I did this:

```
select a1.actor_id as i8opoios1,a2.actor_id as i8opoios2,((count(distinct(g1.genre_name))+count(distinct(g2.genre_name)))>=7) as result from actor as a1
inner join actor as a2 on a1.actor_id!=a2.actor_id

inner join role as r1 on a1.actor_id=r1.actor_id
inner join movie as m1 on m1.movie_id=r1.movie_id
inner join movie_has_genre as mg1 on mg1.movie_id=m1.movie_id
inner join genre as g1 on mg1.genre_id=g1.genre_id

inner join role as r2 on a2.actor_id=r2.actor_id
inner join movie as m2 on m2.movie_id=r2.movie_id
inner join movie_has_genre as mg2 on mg2.movie_id=m2.movie_id
inner join genre as g2 on mg2.genre_id=g2.genre_id

where a1.actor_id<a2.actor_id and mg1.genre_id!=mg2.genre_id 
group by a1.actor_id,a2.actor_id;
```

This query returns me all the pair of actors who have not played on anyone
common movie genre and as a result a 1(TRUE) if combined they played on 7 or more genre and 0(FAlSE) if they hadnt.My question is if anyone has an idea on how can i return only the true statements.

```
Tables and their columns:

actor(actor_id,name)
role(actor_id,movie_id)
movie(movie_id,title)
movie_has_genre(movie_id,genre_id)
genre(genre_id,gender_name)
```

Comment: By *gender* to you mean *genre*? The former indicates the gender (ie male/female) while the later indicates the genre (ie Drama/Comedy) of the movie.

Comment: Edit your question and add an example (only a few rows) of the result of your query

Comment: yeah that was what i meant sorry for my mistake i've been studying on my project like 7 hours and i am little burnt out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition to your where clause to limit the rows.

```
SELECT 
    a1.actor_id as i8opoios1,
    a2.actor_id as i8opoios2,
    IF((count(distinct(g1.genre_name))+count(distinct(g2.genre_name)))>=7,1,0) as result 
FROM actor as a1
INNER JOIN actor as a2 
    on a1.actor_id != a2.actor_id
INNER JOIN role as r1 
    on a1.actor_id = r1.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m1 
    on m1.movie_id = r1.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg1 
    on mg1.movie_id = m1.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre as g1 
    on mg1.genre_id = g1.genre_id
INNER JOIN role as r2 
    on a2.actor_id = r2.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m2 
    on m2.movie_id = r2.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg2 
    on mg2.movie_id = m2.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre as g2 
    on mg2.genre_id = g2.genre_id
WHERE a1.actor_id < a2.actor_id 
    AND mg1.genre_id != mg2.genre_id 
HAVING IF((count(distinct(g1.genre_name))+count(distinct(g2.genre_name)))>=7,1,0) = 1
GROUP BY a1.actor_id,a2.actor_id;
```

Comment: is says invalid use of group function.I thought something like this by myself and i had the same error.

Comment: i removed the if clause from where and i am ran it again.Same result with mine

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a **HAVING** for the aggregate functions. See if that works.

Comment: one thing though group by goes first then having if